# Clicking noise while pedaling

Tags: repair

I have a Trek Domane S4 (carbon) that makes a random "clicking" noise while pedaling. I can feel it thru my feet, so I'm thinking its coming from the crank area, but can't seem to figure it out. I use Mtn bike shoes w/ clipless pedals, could it be the pedals?

Comment: Gee, I don't think this question has been asked before!

Comment: It's hard to imagine this being diagnosable from so little information. Is there anything you can do when riding the bike that makes it click more/less/louder/quieter/anything? If it really is random, it's hard to suggest anything other than taking it to a bike shop and letting one of the mechanics ride it around for a bit.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - Just a [few times](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=click+while+pedaling+is%3Aquestion). You know, here and there.

Comment: Needs a lot more diagnosis.  Please read the linked duplicates to see the advice already given.  Basically you need to isolate things and find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

if the clicks happen when you're pedaling hard or uphill, try tightening the pedals more.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32337)

Comment: @BenediktBauer why isnt this an answer? This was my solution recently and it solved my issue.